# Python - Type issue with file (list and string)

Tags: python, string, list, file, types

I saved a list in a file and when I want to recover it, I do not get a list but a string

My file :

```
[(u'Dan', u'Alon', u'Carla',),(u'Carla', u'Stockton', u'Munich', u'Memoir',)]
```

I tried with split () but I do not get exactly the same list
It's important for the rest of my script to get exactly the same list

My script :

```
def tabBinaire():
with open("data", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        defi = line.split(",")
        print(defi)
        output = cool.DataFrame(defi).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
        print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **ast module**.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
defi = ast.literal_eval(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use eval function.

```
a = "[(u'Dan', u'Alon', u'Carla',),(u'Carla', u'Stockton', u'Munich', u'Memoir',)]"
list_a = eval(a)
print list_a
# [(u'Dan', u'Alon', u'Carla',),(u'Carla', u'Stockton', u'Munich', u'Memoir',)]
```

Comment: Using `eval` when `ast.literal_eval` can do the job is potentially dangerous

Comment: be careful with this `eval()`. It has really great potential!